# React - use single event handler to set state for multiple inputs?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-state-management

I'm new to React and wondering if it's possible to use a single event handler to set the state for many inputs. Namely, I'm not sure how to get the state "key" from the input into the handler, if that makes sense.

```
import React from 'react';

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      id: props.id,
      firstName: props.firstName,
      lastName: props.lastName,
      email: props.email,
    };
  }

  // how do I (can I) use this single handler to independently change the state of multiple inputs?
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ this.state.key // wrong!: this.inputRef.current.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} id={`first_${this.state.id}`} value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} id={`last_${this.state.id}`} value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <input type="email" ref={this.inputRef} id={`email_${this.state.id}`} value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        // imagine ten more inputs
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `{ [propName]: value }` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is more related to JS events handling.

```
handleChange(event) {
      const {name, value} = event.target;

      this.setState({
          [name]: value
      });
    }
```

- `event.target` is the element that fired that event (button, text area,
  etc..) and you can grab whatever attribute you want from it (name,
  type, value, etc..).
- Inside `setState` you've to use similar
  states' names to that of your elements' names attribute. For the code
  snippet you provided you can add a name attribute to the first input
  tag `<input name = "firstName" .... />` and so on.
- Having combinations of inputs of different types at the same time (e.g. text area and checkboxes) are trickier to deal with you might need to modify it a little or using conditions but you get the idea now :)
- One more thing don't bind your handlers inside the `render()` method beacuse with each render a brand new function returns one of the correct ways to bind the handlers is inside the `constructor()` method.